# How can I add an argument in an injectable constructor but still let Nest manage dependency injection?

Tags: nestjs

I have created a custom guard which looks like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyCustomGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
    private reflector: Reflector,
    private myService: MyService,
  ) {}

  async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): Promise<boolean> {
    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    const idParam = request.params.id;
    ...
  }
}
```

I use it like this in my controller:

```
@UseGuards(MyCustomGuard)
@Controller('my-controller')
export class MyController {
 ...
}
```

It works fine, but I would like to set the `id` param key as a parameter when instantiating the guard, like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyCustomGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
    private idKey: string,
    private reflector: Reflector,
    private myService: MyService,
  ) {}

  async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): Promise<boolean> {
    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    const idParam = request.params[idKey];
    ...
  }
}
```

Then I will have to instantiate the guard manually in my controller:

```
@UseGuards(new MyCustomGuard('id', ...?))
@Controller('my-controller')
export class MyController {
  ...
}
```

My problem is that if I do that, then I will have to manually instantiate the other constructor arguments of my guard: the reflector and the service. That is possible but it is something I would rather let Nest manage, for simplicity and performance reasons. Then my question is: is there any way to instantiate the guard manually (so that I can give it the `idKey` argument) but still let Nest manage dependency injection for the other arguments?
It seems that using a `ModuleRef` would work here, but I don't really know if it's the correct way to do it.

Comment: have you tried the [property-based injection](https://docs.nestjs.com/providers#property-based-injection) instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing the `idKey` as a constructor parameter, I would suggest reflecting it as metadata of the class. This way, you could do something like

```js
@IdKey('id')
@UseGuards(MyCustomGuard)
@Controller('my-controller')
export class MyController {
...
}
```

and in your guard you do something like

```js
@Injectable()
export class MyCustomGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
    private reflector: Reflector,
    private myService: MyService,
  ) {}

  async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): Promise<boolean> {
    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    const idParam = request.params.id;
    const idKey = this.getIdKey(context);
    ...
  }

  getIdKey(context: ExecutionContext) {
    return this.reflector.get('id-key', context.getClass());
  }
}
```

This is assuming that your `@IdKey()` looks something like

```js
export const IdKey = (key: string) => SetMetadata(key);
```

where `SetMetadata` comes from `@nestjs/common`

[You can read more about `@SetMetadata()` and metadata rerflection here](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/execution-context)